# Executing a stored procedure fails when placed in transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that I want to execute via a linked server. The query looks like this:

```
USE db1;

SET xact_abort ON;

DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(max);
SET @statement = 'EXECUTE (''INSERT INTO T1(V1, V2) VALUES (1, 2)'') AT LS1';

BEGIN try
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    EXEC Sp_executesql @statement

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END try

BEGIN catch
    IF ( Xact_state() ) = -1
      BEGIN
          PRINT Error_message()

          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
      END

    IF ( Xact_state() ) = 1
      BEGIN
          PRINT 'COMMIT OPEN TRANSACTION'

          COMMIT TRANSACTION
      END

    INSERT INTO tblerrmsg (errornumber, errorseverity, errorstate, errorline, errormessage) EXECUTE Usp_geterrorinfo;
END catch
```

This fails with an entry in my TblErrMsg table.

> ErrorNumber = 8501, ErrorSeverity = 16, ErrorState = 3, ErrorLine = 1, ErrorMessage = MSDTC on server 'XXX' is unavailable.

So I researched for the specific error message and checked if the Distributed Transaction Coordinator Service was running on the server, but this was already the case. Even a restart of the service did not bring any change. Next I tried to remove the transaction and execute the following procedure:

```
USE db1;

DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(max);
SET @statement = 'EXECUTE (''INSERT INTO T1(V1, V2) VALUES (1, 2)'') AT LS1';

BEGIN try
    EXEC Sp_executesql @statement
END try

BEGIN catch
    PRINT Error_message()
END catch
```

And this time it worked. There were no errors and the INSERT also worked. So I'm wondering what really the problem is. Apparently there seems to be no problem with the execution of the procedure nor with the Linked Server connection.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem, or has an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: The second transaction isn't wrapped in a transaction, and the error you were getting previously was specific the using distributed transactions, so it makes sense that the latter doesn't error.

Comment: Unfortunately I still do not understand why the transaction really fails. The error just tells me that MSDTC is not running, which is not the case. In case of an invalid procedure, shouldn't there be an error in the second case (without transaction) as well? Or is there another reason for the error 'MSDTC on server 'XXX' is unavailable' which I did not consider?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're missing the key word DISTRIBUTED when specifying the explicit transaction.

Instead of

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

Try

```
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION
```

According to the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-distributed-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) this is the way to specify "... the start of a Transact-SQL distributed transaction managed by Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC)"

Without the explicit transaction the default behavior afaik is the transaction across linked server is not guaranteed to be atomic and cannot be rolled back.  This why it works when no explicit transaction is specified.

When BEGIN TRANSACTION is specified without 'DISTRIBUTED' the statement is asking something that's not possible when the procedure contains a linked server reference.